# Calculate the expected value for this markov chain

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, statistics

> Harry's restaurant changes year after year between the states $0$
>   (bankrupt), $1$ (almost bankrupt) and $2$ (solvent).
>
> The transition matrix is 
>   $P= \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1    &  0    &  0   \\ 
> 1/2  &  1/4  &  1/4 \\  
> 1/2  &  1/4  &  1/4 
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Calculate the expected value for the amount of years till state $0$ is
>   reached, if we started from state $2$.

I took this question from an exam and try to solve it but I'm not sure how to do this correct? I'm a bit confused we need to work with expected value to calculate the required steps / years to get from state $2$ to state $0$. At least that's how I understood this so far.

It all sounds like I need to solve some recursive relations. Let $h(k)$ be the expected number of steps / years in this example until we reach the state $0$ when you are in state $2$. So we have that 
$$h(2)=0$$

because when you are in state $2$, you need $0$ steps / years to reach $2$. Then for $k=1$

$$h(1) = 1+0.25h(1)+0.25h(2)+0.5h(0)$$

because when you are in state $1$ you will need a step ($+1$) so you will reach with probability $0.25$ state $1$ again and with probability $0.25$ state $2$ and with probability $0.5$ state $0$.

Similarly we do this for $h(0):$

$$h(0) = 1+1h(0)$$

But from here I don't really know how to continue to get the system and calculate the expected number pf steps with that? : /

Comment: "Calculate the expected value for the amount of years till state 0 is reached, if we started from state 2" vs "when you are in state 2, you need 0 steps / years to reach 2" Confusing states 2 and 0?

Comment: @Did Yeah.. I should have better read what I have written before posting it / handing it in next time :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $h(k)$ be the expected time to reach state $0$ if we started from state $\color{blue}k$.

Then $h(0)=0$.

And if we start with state $1$, with probability $\frac12$ we reach state $0$, with probability $\frac14$ we reach state $1$, and with probability $\frac14$ we reach state $2$.

Hence $$h(1)=1+\frac12h(0)+\frac14h(1)+\frac14h(2)$$

Similarly,

$$h(2)=1+\frac12h(0)+\frac14h(1)+\frac14h(2)$$

Substituting $h(0)=0$, we have

$$h(1)=1+\frac14h(1)+\frac14h(2)\tag{1}$$

$$h(2)=1+\frac14h(1)+\frac14h(2)\tag{2}$$

Subtracting both equation we have $$h(1)=h(2)\tag{3}$$

Use equation $(3)$ and $(2)$ to solve for $h(2)$.

Comment: Why do we have "+1" in all the equations except the last one? Why do we need to +1?

Comment: for example, in the first equation, we take $1$ step and then we can reach state 0 with probability $\frac12$, state $1$ with probability $\frac14$ and state $2$ with probability $\frac14$.

Comment: I still do not get it why we need to add 1. When you subtract (1) and (2) to get (3), the +1 is cancelled.

Comment: $h$ denote the time to reach step $0$. It is equal to one step more than if you start from the next state that you might end up with.

Answer (score 5):

This is a Markov chain with an absorbing state. Denote by $Q$ the non-absorbing block of the transition matrix. The fundamental matrix is $N= (I-Q)^{-1} = $

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
-\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{pmatrix}
 ^{-1}
= 
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 3\\
 3 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This matrix's entry $(i, j)$ is the expected value of visits at $i$ before being absorbed if the chain starts at $j$ (or the other way around, I don't remember, but luckily it doesn't matter in this case the matrix is symmetric). So the answer is

$$\frac{1}{2}(3+1) = 2.$$

---

**EDIT**

The meanings of the entries of $N$ are actually other way around (since the transition matrix is given such that "rows sum to $1$"). Here's a [reference](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter11.pdf) (page 15 of the pdf (or 419 as the page number)).

Comment: What's the reason of calculating "\frac{1}{2}(3+1) = 2"? How do you get that?

Comment: @user546106 It comes from summing the second row of the fundamental matrix. The fundamental matrix has as entries the expected number of visits to each state (corresponding to column) starting from a particular state (corresponding row) before absorption. Expectation is linear, so the total expected number of steps before absorption is given by the sum.