# On average how many keystrokes will it take to randomly hit the keypad of four characters (ABCD) to write DAC for the first time?

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate on average how many keystrokes will it take to randomly hit the keypad of four characters (ABCD) to write DAC for the first time. For example, ABCDAAADAC had 10 keystrokes before the first appearance of DAC.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us your work (how you get to 64) we may be able to help.

Comment: Where did H come from? (ABCDAAHDAC)

Comment: Are you familiar with First Step Analysis ?

Comment: I edited it. The H was a mistake.

Comment: I am not familiar with it no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is indeed as you wrote it here (as a commenter pointed out, there is an "H" in the $10$ letter example you gave that doesn't make sense given the stated problem), the answer is indeed $64$ steps. This can be solved using [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) modelling (as maybe you did). Using this you find out that from "DA" it still takes an expected additional $48$ steps to reach "DAC", from just "D" it takes an expected $60$ steps and from the starting postion $64$ steps. See the solution of [this problem on stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634154/calculate-the-expected-value-for-this-markov-chain) for how this works if you are unfamiliar with that.

So if the problem is copied correctly, and there are no other assumptions (the monkey may "prefer" certain keys or have a higher probability of pressing the same key twice in a rown), then I'm at a loss what your professor has in mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The H was my mistake while writing the question.